# How to sync notifications between two android devices?

Tags: notifications, push-notifications

I have two android devices, but I usually use only one at a time. I want to see the other device notifications without using any computer or web app.

I can use AirDroid to see notifications, but only in web or desktop app. I can log in the web app using Chrome Browser for Android, but I don't receive any notification. I only can see notificacions in the other device if I check manually the Airdroid web page.

I can use also Pushbullet to see notifications, but only with browser extension (I  only checked with Chrome one but I imagine it's also working with the other browsers). As I cannot install the browser extension in Chrome Browser for Android, this option is not valid to use within a smartphone.

Pushbullet offered in a previous version a beta feature to sync notifications between devices, but [this feature has been dismissed](https://www.reddit.com/r/PushBullet/comments/3elzth/did_notification_mirroringforwarding_between/).

Then, there is an option to be aware of notifications of one Android device from other one?